# Bind data to grid views

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, gridview, c#-3.0

I have below format result set from query,

[image]

and I wish to show above query result in below format using datatable or any other option in Gridview.

[image]

Can some one please help me.

Comment: cloud you please upload a image for what you want in result gridview? As you mention **with proper IsSelected property**. you can use  Itemtemplate and add checkbox if value 1 then select or not. for reference: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-Check-Uncheck-CheckBox-in-GridView-based-on-DataTable-value-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Payer's list are not fixed. This payers are depends on number of payers available in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Payer's list are not fixed. This payers are depends on number of
>   payers available in the system.

First off all try to retrieve data from database using pivot columns.
[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a66e94/1)

Then use that data to bound `GridView` dynamically.
Bind grid with `TemplateField` as per columns created dynamically:

```
protected void bindgrid()
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter sqd = new SqlDataAdapter("selectdata", con)) // here selectdata is my stored procedure in SQL Server
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqd.Fill(dt);

        ViewState["data"] = dt;

        for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            tfield.HeaderText = "Payers"+j;
            grid1.Columns.Add(tfield);
        }

        grid1.DataSource = dt;
        grid1.DataBind();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Bind CheckBox to those columns whose values are 1,0 or null

```
protected void updategrid()
{
        for(int k = 0; k < grid1.Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            DataTable dtl = (DataTable)ViewState["data"];

            for (int j = 1; j < dtl.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dtl.Rows[k][j].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
                    ch.ID = "checkbox" + j;
                    ch.Checked = true;
                    grid1.Rows[k].Cells[j].Controls.Add(ch);
                }
                else if (dtl.Rows[k][j].ToString() == "0" || dtl.Rows[k][j].ToString() == "" || dtl.Rows[k][j].ToString() == null)
                {
                    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
                    ch.ID = "checkbox" + j;
                    ch.Checked = false;
                    grid1.Rows[k].Cells[j].Controls.Add(ch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Output Screen Short]